# Terminal freezes on big output from command

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, terminal, iterm2, pty

I use `iTerm2` + `Oh My Zsh` on my mac. Everything was working fine till yesterday.

On any AWS box that I SSH to, I am able to run commands that generate few lines of output.
Like `uptime`, `vmstat 1 300 -w` also works(I am assuming, since it prints one line in one second)

But If I try to run `ps -ef` or `history` or `htop` or `cat` a few 100 lines of a file, the screen spits some output on the screen and then freezes. I cant do `ctrl+c` or anything else except terminate the SSH connection(~.) and then SSH again.[image]

Everything works fine on my local machine, even on a dev machine that's a VM on OpenStack. Its just all the AWS boxes where the problem is coming up.

I am not sure whats happening or how to debug this. Please help.

P.S. - `ps -ef | less` works, if that means anything.

P.P.S. - I SSH-ed with two terminals into an AWS box.
got `pts/0` for one `pts/1` for other.

Then I did `echo Hello > /dev/pts/1` from my `pts/0`, `pts/1` gets **Hello**, but if I do `ps -ef > /dev/pts/1` I see few lines of output on `pts/1` and then it freezes.

Now I doubt iTerm has anything to do with this now. pts is not able to handle big character stream, but why is it happening?